# Hard drive is not detected in BIOS

Tags: hard-drive

I recently starting having problems with my netbook. I accidentally stood on it the other day, and since then it hasn't been booting up. I checked the BIOS and the hard drive is not in the boot options, and also checked at SATA info and it said `serial ATA : empty`. I tried putting in a new hard drive, but I still had the same problem. Does anyone know what's wrong with it and why the hard drive is not being detected?

Comment: "Does anyone know what's wrong with it and why the hard drive is not being detected?"  Yes: "I accidentally stood on it the other day".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your motherboard has been damaged since it will not detect a new confirmed-working drive at the bios.

Inspect the bus connecting the drive to the motherboard. if there are any removable parts (some laptops use a connector) and make sure it is intact and properly seated, and try again.

If the bus looks fine, it is likely that the damage is on the board, so you'll have to replace the whole thing.

if your motherboard has a second IO bus, you may be able to reconnect the drive to it, but , even if it works, in my experience damage to motherboard components tends to "spread" to other subsystems over time, due to electrical anomalies caused by the damaged components.